# Add Content Next to the line of a given search pattern in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, generator, text-manipulation, thor

I'm making a custom rails 3 generator, I want to add some content after the attributes line in the following locale file, for example, inserting "user: 'User'"

```
es:
  activerecord:
    attributes:
      user: 'User'
      # some stuff
    errors:
      # some other stuff
```

how I can do that, considering that the attributes line could be in any position of the text?

Answer (score 1):

There are a few options, each of them have drawbacks:

- Inject with `gsub_file`: hard and error prone
- Load the YAML, update the Hash and overwrite it: you may loose comments and other minor changes that won't affect the data
- Create another YAML with only these new data (Rails loads all the locale files on startup): you may end up with many locale files